# Persisting a member variable in JPA, when only the type is important

Tags: java, jpa, serialization, jpa-2.0

**Problem:** How to store a field when only its type is important.

**Description:** I have simplified the problem description to highlight the issue. The class `Dragon` has a behavior, `Roar`, which is stored as a member variable. A `Roar` typically has no state and doesn't need to be saved. However, the `Dragon` needs to know what specific type of `Roar` it has when it is recreated.

```
@Entity
public class Dragon implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private double height;
    private Roar roar;

    public String roar() {
        return roar.roar();
    }
}

public interface Roar {
    String roar();
}

public class QuietRoar implements Roar {
    public String roar() {
        return "grr.."; // In real scenario, lots of logic occurs here. 
}

public class LoudRoar implements Roar {
    public String roar() {
        return "AHHHGRRRR";  // More logic here.
}
```

**Possible solution:**
Make the `roar` field transient and store an additional field of type `Class` which holds the class type of the `roar` field. The `Dragon` class then becomes:

```
@Entity
public class Dragon implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private double height;
    @Transient
    private Roar roar;
    private Class<? extends Roar> roarType; 

    public void setRoar(Roar roar) {
        this.roar = roar;
        roarType = roar.getClass();
    }

    public String roar() {
        if(roar == null) {
            try {
                roar = roarType.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex ) {
                // oo ohh..
            }
        }
        return roar.roar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EclipseLink you can use a Converter for this.

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_converter.htm#CHDEHJEB

Specifically you can use a ClassInstanceConverter which store the name of the class in the column.

JPA 2.1 will also define a Converter concept.

Comment: I have one concern with this approach. It solves the issue with persisting with JPA, however, the class still implements Serializable, and if I attempted to serialize an instance of this class, I would get a runtime exception, as `Roar` doesn't implement serializable and would not be marked transient.

Comment: I think this issue could be avoided by utilizing property access such that the transient keyword wont affect the JPA.